# Correct design: a Post can have one User (author) plus many Users (tagged users)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema, rails-models

I have a situation where I'm getting a bit stuck.

A Post can have a User (as an author), and a Post can also have many Users (as a post can have other users tagged in it).

In my Post model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

In my User model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
```

It works fine generally, but is getting rather stuck when I want to include users on my posts query, and sort the posts by the author's name.

What should the correct design be? Perhaps replace user_id in Post with author_id?

Comment: Do you have database table where you store data for many-to-many relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine `User` and `Users` messing up your joins. But mind you, as far as my experience this is something that rails does not solve well. Just renaming it `author` (whilst improving the readability/expressing the intention better) will not help, since it will still point to the same table `users`.

When doing multiple joins with rails, it is very hard to express your conditions correctly. Rails creates aliases for your tables on the fly, unfortunately I have not find a way to address these aliases in my conditions.

So I think you will either have to resort to a handcrafted sql (which will be fast) or use rails, and get the posts sorted on author-name first, and then retrieve the list of tagged users per post second (which will be slower, but pure ruby).

I would go for the second option first, and optimize to the first if needed.

[UPDATE: add a scope definition]

Personally, I do not favor `default_scope` and instead would propose to define an explicit scope

```
scope :with_authors_sorted, lambda { 
  Post.includes(:type).includes(:user).
       order('year DESC, week DESC, users.display_name ASC, posts.created_at DESC') 
}
```

which you can then just use in your controller.

```
@posts = Post.with_authors_sorted
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I prefer the purity of this approach. Do you know what my default scope should look like if I want posts to be sorted by the user's display_name? is this appropriate 

   `default_scope includes(:type) / default_scope includes(:user) / default_scope order('year DESC, week DESC, users.display_name ASC, posts.created_at DESC')`